# Getting top albums from last.fm

Tags: python, last.fm

Im getting the top artists from a specific country from lastfm api. Im getting the name of each artist and store in the `artists{}` with success with:

```
import requests

api_key = "0929f1144e531702a5563c887cbbade0"

ID = 0
artists = {}

for i in range(1, 3):

    artists_response = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&format=json&page=' + str(i) + '&api_key=' + api_key)
    artists_data = artists_response.json()

    for artist in artists_data["topartists"]["artist"]:

        name = artist["name"]

        artists[ID] = {}
        artists[ID]['ID'] = ID
        artists[ID]['name'] = name
        ID += 1
```

But now for each artist I want to get the top5 albums and store in the `albums{},` the artist name, the artist id, the name the album, and the url of the album.

For example for each artist, I want to get one record for each album of the top5 albums like this:

```
 "Artist": "U2", "ID": 175, "ArtistID": 10, "Title": Achtung    Baby",  
 "Image": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/a482040d21924ddacd5fe75dedbb1ef2.png"},
 "URL": "https://www.last.fm/music/U2/Achtung+Baby"}, "487": {"Date": "2004-01-01"

 "Artist": "U2", "ID": 176, "ArtistID": 10, "Description": "None", "Title": "Boy", 


 ... and then the same for the other 3 albums of the top5
```

Im doing this with the code below, but its not working correctly. The artistId appears always as "0" and it only appears the 5 albums of the first artist. Do you know where is the issue?

```
albums = {}

for i,v in artists.items():
    chosen = artists[i]['name'].replace(" ", "+")
    topalbums_response = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&format=json&artist=' + chosen + '&api_key=' + api_key + '&limit=5')
    albums_data = topalbums_response.json()

    for album in albums_data['topalbums']['album']:

        name = album["name"]
        url = album["url"]

        albums[ID] = {}
        albums[ID]['ID'] = ID
        albums[ID]['artist'] = artists[i]['name']
        albums[ID]['artistID'] = artists[i]['ID']
        albums[ID]['name'] = name
        albums[ID]['url'] = url

        for image in album['image']:
            if (image["size"] == "large"):
                if (image["size"] is not None):
                    image = image["#text"]
                    albums[ID]['image'] = image

        ID += 1

        print(albums)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your album loop to start like this:

```
for _, v in artists.items():
    chosen = v['name'].replace(" ", "+")
```

Additionally, I notice you are assigning ID = 0 at the start of artists, but referencing it within the albums, you might want to look at that.

====
EDIT:

The following code works for me although I'm not really sure of what format you want to get so it is incomplete.

```
import requests

api_key = "0929f1144e531702a5563c887cbbade0"

artists_url = (
    'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists'
    '&country=spain&format=json&page={}&api_key={}'
)

artists = []

for page in range(1, 3):
    artists_data = requests.get(artists_url.format(str(page), api_key)).json()
    for ID, artist in enumerate(artists_data["topartists"]["artist"]):
        artists.append((ID, artist["name"]))


albums = {}
albums_url = (
    'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums'
    '&format=json&artist={}&api_key={}&limit=5'
)


for ID, artist in artists[:3]:   ### LIMITED to first three artists for testing.
    print('\n------\n{} {}'.format(ID, artist))
    chosen = artist.replace(" ", "+")
    albums_data = requests.get(albums_url.format(chosen, api_key)).json()

    for album in albums_data['topalbums']['album']:

        name = album["name"]
        url = album["url"]
        print('{}\n{}'.format(name, url))
        print(album)
        print()
#        albums[ID] = {}
#        albums[ID]['ID'] = ID
#        albums[ID]['artist'] = artists[i]['name']
#        albums[ID]['artistID'] = artists[i]['ID']
#        albums[ID]['name'] = name
#        albums[ID]['url'] = url
#
#        for image in album['image']:
#            if (image["size"] == "large"):
#                if (image["size"] is not None):
#                    image = image["#text"]
#                    albums[ID]['image'] = image
#
#        ID += 1
#
#        print(albums)
#        print()
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not working.  The artistID now appears but then the albums that appear associated to an artist are from other artist, and also its not returning all the results, just one.

Comment: added an edit to the answer about the fact that you are initiating ID before the artists loop but not before the albums loop.

Comment: I added  "ID = 0" before "albuns = {}" but I get the same issue.

Comment: I posted my modified version of your code.  Note that I'm using enumerate, instead of manually generating an ID number.  Also, I put the artists in a list.

Comment: Thanks.. But do you know why when arrives at count/id equal to 49 it returns to 0 instead of 50?